# why the state changes even when the conditions are not satisfied?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I created two buttons on a form, when I click Fenced button if Description, analyse and conclusion are not empty so the state value should be Fenced else nothing should happens and when I click Not yet button, if Description or analyse or conclusion are not empty the state value should change to In progress.

here my two buttons Fenced and Not yet:

```html
 <group name="group_tests_buttons" class="oe_button_box" col="6">
                        <button name="write_new"
                            type="object"
                            class="oe_stat_button"
                            string="Fenced">  
                        </button>
                       <button name="write_new2"
                            type="object"
                            class="oe_stat_button"
                            string="Not yet">
                        </button>
```

and here is the functions for the two buttons:

```html
    @api.depends('Description','analyse','conclusion')
    def write_new(self):
        if self.Description != "" and self.analyse != "" and self.conclusion != "":
            self.state = "Fenced"   


    @api.depends('Description','analyse','conclusion')
    def write_new2(self): 
        if self.Description != "" or self.analyse != "" or self.conclusion != "":
            self.state = "In progress"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In odoo don't use this for empty field:

```
self.Description != ""
```

empty field or null in odoo are False:

```
self.Description != False
```